# Where should I ask questions about technology recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for an appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask a technology recommendation question.

My question would be along the lines of:

> I am looking for a Microsoft Azure storage solution to save unstructured data that comes from a web crawler like html code and images.

Comment: The obvious possibility is http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, though I'm not 100% sure if a "storage solution" is among the software they take questions on.

Answer (score 1):

Your words "technology recommendations" and "I am looking for a.." generally mean your question will be far too broad and/or bring opinionated answers.

So I'm not sure any of the Stack sites would gladly accommodate such a question.

You'd be better off trailing the internet for solutions already advertised and discussed in forums/websites etc. And when you eventually find one which suits you, and have a specific question about it, find the most appropriate Stack site and ask a question which can be answered.